# How Do I hide about me setting inside SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365

[image]

Hello I would like to know how I can hide this by using CSS what code would i need to add in to hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following css:

```
a#O365_SubLink_ShellAboutMe {
    display: none;
}
```